# Xcode SVN does not show remote

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

i have set up an SVN on my remote debian server.

When i add a repository on Xcode using svn://myIPAdress/project it's ok, xcode sees it and i can get the project i have copied using a svn client.

Nevertheless when i make changes on my project "Push to remote" is not enabled. So when i make commits nothing changes on my server.

I want use svn so i can get my project from everywhere.

How can i enabled "Push to Remote" so changes i make on my projects change on my remote server ?

Thank you for all answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to check out the project from your server first in order to connect it. Menu `Source Control` -> `Check Out...`. After you're done, you can `Commit` your new/changed files using `Source Control` -> `Commit...` or from the context menu of your files and folders.